# Not able to drag map vertically Highmaps

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to create world map using highchart, when I import specific version of highmaps I am able to drag and navigate the map horizontally and vertically. But on using latest version of highmaps.js I am not able to drag it vertically, though I am able to drag the mapChart horizontally.

Comment: Looks like a bug - reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12671